# FileDialog getFilterIndex() Method returning -1

Tags: java, linux, swt

I am new to dialogs in Java SWT, and i'm trying to make a file chooser. I took as example the snippet from eclipse website: https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet72.java
I need to know the selected filter by the user, I do that by doing something:
 `int idx = dialog.getFilterIndex(); followed by String filter = dialog.getFilterNames[idx];`
On linux (ubuntu 18.04) `dialog.getFilterIndex()` is returning -1 even if I choose a filter. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like Eclipse bug [546256](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=546256)

Comment: Looks like it. Maybe post your answer so I can make it as accepted answer. Thank you. @greg-449

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like Eclipse bug [546256](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=546256).

This bug is still open. The bug reports suggests it is a problem with the GTK 3 `GtkNativeChooserDialog` code.